# Convert date from dd-mm-yy to dd-mm-yyyy using python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a date input 'date_dob' which is '20-Apr-53'
I tried converting this to  format yyyy-mm-dd using following code:

```
print pd.to_datetime(date_dob,format = '%d-%b-%y')
```

which returns '2053-04-20 00:00:00' instead of '1953-04-20 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly check for the year, and then subtract it by 100 years as:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> my_date = '20-Apr-53'
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_date, '%d-%b-%y')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2053, 4, 20, 0, 0)
#                   ^ year = 2053  
>>> if d.year > 2000:
...     d = d.replace(year=d.year-100)  # subtract year by 100
... 
>>> d
datetime.datetime(1953, 4, 20, 0, 0)
#                   ^ year = 1953
>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # %Y instead of %y, reason mentioned below
'1953-04-20'
#  ^ all four digit of year
```

Using `%Y` instead of `%y` because:

- `%y`: displays last two digit of year
- `%Y`: display all four digit of year

Answer (score 0):

The official [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is your friend. Consult it ;-)

> %y -> Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.
>
> %Y -> Year with century as a decimal number.

So use this approach

```
format='%d-%b-%Y'
```